# How to make a Object in a class physically move using JS and p5.js

Tags: javascript, oop, p5.js

So far, I've created a class which generates a circle. I'm trying to make this circle move/vibrate constantly  but I'm not sure what is the best way to add a move function with OOP. Also, when I create the 'face' object in the draw function my page crashes.

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(350, 350, WEBGL);
  background('white')
  let face = new Face();
}

class Face {
  constructor() {
    this.basicFace(100, random(10,30),0,0);
  }


  basicFace(radius, steps, centerX, centerY) {
  var xValues = [];
  var yValues = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < steps; i++) {
    let rad = radius + random(-radius / 50, radius / 50) 
    xValues[i] = (centerX + rad * cos(2 * PI * i / steps));
    yValues[i] = (centerY + rad * sin(2 * PI * i / steps));
  }
  beginShape();
  strokeWeight(4)
    for (let i = 0; i < xValues.length; i++) {
      curveVertex(xValues[i], yValues[i]);
    }
  endShape(CLOSE);

}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.4.0/lib/p5.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, one reason why creating new `Face` instances in your `draw()` function might cause the page to hang would be because the `draw()` function runs many times per second, and in JavaScript large numbers of allocations (such as creating new instances of a class) can be bad for performance. However, simply allocating one class instance per call to `draw()` wouldn't normally cause a problem. If you are adding those instances to a data structure such as an array on the other hand, that could cause you page to use an excessive amount of memory and eventually hang. Without seeing the exact code that is causing the hang it is hard to say.

If you want to implement the above sketch in an Object Oriented way, then you should take the following steps:

1. Give your class some constructor parameters that define it's properties, such as location and size, and store those as instance fields.
2. Separate your class behaviors from the constructor (i.e. give it a method that causes it to be displayed.
3. Instantiate it once and then call that instance method in `draw()` so that it is displayed each frame.

```js
let face;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(350, 350, WEBGL);
  face = new Face(100, random(10, 30), 0, 0);
}

function draw() {
  background('white');
  face.show();
}

class Face {
  constructor(radius, steps, centerX, centerY) {
    this.radius = radius;
    this.steps = steps;
    this.centerX = centerX;
    this.centerY = centerY;
  }

  show() {
    var xValues = [];
    var yValues = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.steps; i++) {
      let rad = this.radius + random(-this.radius / 50, this.radius / 50)
      xValues[i] = (this.centerX + rad * cos(2 * PI * i / this.steps));
      yValues[i] = (this.centerY + rad * sin(2 * PI * i / this.steps));
    }
    
    strokeWeight(4);
    beginShape();
    for (let i = 0; i < xValues.length; i++) {
      curveVertex(xValues[i], yValues[i]);
    }
    
    endShape(CLOSE);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.4.0/lib/p5.js"></script>
```

Additionally, when you are displaying your curve, it is not necessary to create arrays for the x and y values in one loop and then call `curveVertex()` in a separate loop. Instead you can combine these loops and avoid unnecessary array allocations.

```
      show() {
        strokeWeight(4);
        beginShape();
        for (let i = 0; i < this.steps; i++) {
          let rad = this.radius + random(-this.radius / 50, this.radius / 50);
          curveVertex(
            this.centerX + rad * cos(2 * PI * i / this.steps),
            this.centerY + rad * sin(2 * PI * i / this.steps)
          );
        }
        
        endShape(CLOSE);
      }
```

Comment: One thing to be aware of: when using `curveVertex` you need to consider that it takes 2 extra vertices, at the beginning and end of your curve, in order to draw the correct number of line segments. When you start a curve with `curveVertex`, that first vertex is only used to determine then angle of the curve where it starts at the **second** vertex in the list. Likewise the last vertex only determines the angle of the curve as it reaches the second to last vertex.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Last question, is there anyway of doing this without using background() to replace the old drawing? For example, when I do move(3) and use show() it will create a duplicate drawing instead of  moving the original one.
`move(x){this.centerX = this.centerX + x; }`

Comment: Well, you could do that yes. But it is not conceptually compatible with the vibration effect caused by the addition of a random offset to the radius for each point. If you want multiple animated instances of `Face` then you are better of making a separate instance with the new position. If you changed your implementation to be static instead of animated then you could potentially eliminate the need to use `background()` and just do additive drawing. That is usually more appropriate for a sketch that isn't using `draw()` at all and instead draws graphics in response to events.